# How do I move to a forward commit?

Tags: git

I was testing changes in git and I checked out a previous commit:

> git log
>
> commit 223090
>
> commit 223089

`git checkout 223089`

When I do a git log I do no longer see 223090....
A `git status` shows

```
HEAD detached at 223089
```

How can I find the actual SHA of the latest commit since it no longer shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git checkout  creates a new branch with HEAD at the 
A `git branch` lists all the branches, and in order to revert back I needed to stash/discard my changes and do a `git checkout <branch name>` in order to get back to where I was.

Comment: You don't have to undo your changes, could have `git stash`'d the changes and applied them back later with `git stash pop`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git reflog` to find the last head you were at before checking out or you could even do `git checkout ORIG_HEAD`.

`ORIG_HEAD` is a special tag to a commit, stores the original head before a command was ran.